# file writing operation in tcl takes lot of time

Tags: tcl

```
set filePointer [open "fileName" "r"]
set fileWritePointer [open "fileNameWrite" "w"]
set lines [split [read $filePointer] "\n"]
close $filePointer
set length [llength $lines]
for {set i 0} {$i<$length} {incr i} {
        if {[regexp "Matching1" $line]} {
           puts $fileWritePointer $line
        }
        if {[regexp "Matching" $line]} {
           puts $fileWritePointer $line
        }
}
close $fileWritePointer
```

I am reading all the lines of the file at a time and splitting it by new line character and reading each line at a time inside the for loop.

After some syntax checks using regexp for the lines I am dumping only selected lines into a new file using the below syntax.

```
puts $filePointer $line
```

My file has around 2 million lines of code.
Like this many regexp matching is present roughly around 1.5.

Comment: You should better read line by line. `while {[gets $fp line]!=-1} { # process here; } close $fp`

Comment: @Dinesh: I have tried reading line by line without using the list but it takes a lot of time when compared to this approach. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139120/how-to-read-a-large-file-line-by-line-using-tcl]

Comment: We need some more details. For example, you mean that your file has 2 millions of lines? On which operating system? Ho much time it take? Is the read part slow, the write or both? And tcl version.

Comment: @ravi507 the post you linked says that you have to care about the memory. You just said your file have 2 millions line, but nothing about how long those lines are. In your case you have to consider a list of 2 millions elements in memory. Maybe you could try to check the program memory print.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini : I am using CentOS release 5.6 (Final) and tcl version is 8.5. Read part is quicker than write part.

Comment: @ravi507 please update your post and add more code on your writing part.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini : Now memory is not an issues but performance is an issue.

Comment: @ravi507 I know we have a lot of gig of RAM today, but *Tcl*, like any other, need time to allocate memory and to access a very big list.

Comment: Two million lines of text is usually less than 160MB. On modern systems, that's a _trivial_ amount, and it's much easier to work with data when it is all in memory. But for truly large files, streaming processing is faster because it involves less overall memory use (because paging is comparatively slow, even to an SSD).

Comment: @ravi507, are you writing to a local or remote file system?

Comment: Is this REALLY your code? I can't see where the variable `line` is being assigned; I'd expect an error when you access it. If you left out the line `set line [lindex $lines $i]`, which is plausible, try replacing `for {set i 0}...` and the `lindex` line to  `foreach line $lines` which will be (a bit) quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing *why* the code is slow (or what exactly you're using a baseline for measurement against) it's hard to be sure what to do to accelerate it. However, you can try switching to streaming processing:

```
set fin [open "fileName"]
set fout [open "fileNameWrite" "w"]
while {[gets $fin line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp "Matching1" $line]} {
        puts $fout $line
    }
    if {[regexp "Matching" $line]} {
        puts $fout $line
    }
}
close $fout
close $fin
```

You should make sure that your regular expressions are constant values for the duration of the processing to avoid recompiling them for every line (which would be *very* slow!) though those constant values *can* be stored in variables, so long as those variables are used without anything being added to them:

```
set RE1 "Matching1"
set RE2 "Matching"
# Note: these variables are NOT assigned to below! They are just used!

set fin [open "fileName"]
set fout [open "fileNameWrite" "w"]
while {[gets $fin line] >= 0} {
    # Added “--” to make sure that the REs are never interpreted as anything else
    if {[regexp -- $RE1 $line]} {
        puts $fout $line
    }
    if {[regexp -- $RE2 $line]} {
        puts $fout $line
    }
}
close $fout
close $fin
```

You might also get extra speed by choosing the right encodings, putting all this code in a procedure, etc. As noted, it's hard to be sure what is the best thing to try without knowing why the code is actually slow, and that in part depends on the system on which it is being run.

Comment: Also, don't use `seek` if you want speed; it forces a buffer flush.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need regular expression matching? String matching is likely to be faster.

Can more than one match be made against the same line, and in that case do you really need the line to be written once for each match? If not, you can speed things up by skipping the rest of the matching attempts once one has succeeded:

```
if {[regexp -- $RE1 $line]} {
    puts $fout $line
} elseif {[regexp -- $RE2 $line]} {
    puts $fout $line
} elseif { ... } {
```

or

```
if {
    [regexp -- $RE1 $line] ||
    [regexp -- $RE2 $line] ||
    ...
} then {
    puts $fout $line
}
```

or

```
switch -regexp -- $line \
    $RE1 - \
    $RE2 - \
    ...  - \
    default {
        puts $fout $line
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!!! the execution time has started to reduce by using elseif conditions instead of if .